# How to get all checked nodes in bootstrap tree-view

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-treeview

I am using boostrap treeview, https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview, and i don't know how to get all checked nodes

Comment: I see a method getSelected () in the GitHub u referred. It's not working?? Or it does not serve your purpose?

Comment: I know there is a method getSelected, but i need to get checked nodes, not the selected nodes. I use the tree-view with checkbox, not with select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the new version has a new method `getChecked()`

https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/releases/tag/v1.2.0

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @WekerleTibor, if it is working, kindly select my answer as the accepted answer :)